# How can I control my gazebo model using keyboard?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi eveyone !

I have built a small model of a small cart having 4 tyres. I have applied revolute joints for all the tyres. Now I can control this cart in gazebo by giving values of force to these joints. But I want to control this cart using my keyboard. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206490/how-can-i-control-my-gazebo-model-using-keyboard-?/) by [akshay5059](https://answers.ros.org/users/21984/akshay5059/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are using ROS alongside gazebo, you will want to add a drivetrain plugin to your URDF or SDF model. If you look at [this link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) scroll down and you will see either Differential Drive or Skid Steering Drive. You can just copy and paste the code into your URDF (if its SDF then dont include the  tags) and specify the respective joints of your robot.

This ROS-Gazebo plugin will then basically act as a node that subscribes to a "/cmd_vel" topic, and you can install the package "ros-indigo-key-teleop" (assuming your on indigo) to be able to use your keyboard to send a command velocity.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2